# Combining 3 shapefiles indices to a single index in a single shapefile in ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, shapefile

I have different polygon shapefiles, each having an index of accessibility within an administrative region ranging from 0 to 1 as an attribute.  The suitability increases from 1 to 0. How can I combine the three in ArcGIS to get one indicator?
I have assigned each attributes within a shapefile a scale of 1 to 5 depending on increasing suitabilty then summed the three up and standardized. Is this logical
I have full licence with all extensions

Comment: Please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/168828/edit) the question to include answers to the following:  What license level to do have for ArcGIS for Desktop? What extensions do you have available? What have you tried?  Should the analysis be in vector or raster space?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to [convert](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//001200000030000000) this shapefiles into the raster files with value field as your accessibility index and then try to use [Raster calculator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000z7000000.htm) to get what you want.

You could use sum of these rasters, or mean or whatever you want.